# Progress Bar in Searching Files

Tags: java, netbeans, progress-bar

Hi I have a program which is searching files that are different and identical to the whole directory of two chosen folder. But my problem is that when the two directories have a large file. UI look seems it was hang. In prevention of it i use progress bar so the user will know how long will it took in searching all the directories. But the problem is that the progress bar was execute when searching is already done. How will I let the progress bar start when the user click certain button? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: yes. I used the tutorial but I notice that progress bar will start when the searching of files was already done. I have a table to display all my files and when all files are already displayed, then the progress bar will start. But i used to execute the progress bar in my button to search all files

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sylouuu/V7a3Y/

```
 - Your progress bar will start if button is clicked and stop this when search is completed
 - In this example you can set duration of progress bar so you know what is your searching algorithm max time you can set same here. Also you can change maxwidth and can remove percentage
```

Comment: Please include the code from the jsfiddle and do not format your description as code.